# Why a Listbox DataTemplate does not use the Windows.Resources styles?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, listbox, datatemplate

I have the following XAML (simplified):

```
<Window ...

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>

        <ListBox ItemsSource=...
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="-" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Hours, StringFormat={}{0:00}}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=":" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Minutes, StringFormat={}{0:00}}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=":" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Seconds, StringFormat={}{0:00}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        ...
```

With this code the Style defined in the Window.Resources is not being applied to the TextBlock inside the DataTemplate but it is on other TextBlocks on the Window.

If I copy the Style and set it in the DataTemplate resources like this:

```
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
```

Then it works. Any idea why do I need to duplicate the style?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a WPF quirk. When a control doesn't inherit from `Control`, but directly from `FrameworkElement`, implicit style lookup inside a template skips directly to the application resources. If you put the style in the application resources (`App.xaml`) it would work.

Alternatively, you can use a named resource and `BasedOn` to reference it:

```
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyTextStyle}" />
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
```

Answer (score 4):

Implicit `Styles` will apply in templates only to types that inherit from `System.Windows.Controls.Control` and since `TextBlock` inherits directly from `System.Windows.FrameworkElement` it won't work. You have to either give your style `x:Key` and use it explicitly or declare your style in `Application.Resources` but then it will apply to all `TextBlocks` and by this I mean basically every displayed bit of text, in whole application

Comment: Overriding `DefaultStyleKey` and writing implicit style in your `Window` is something different. Basically when style is evaluated for non `System.Windows.Controls.Control` element it will not go beyond that template to check other element resources but go straight to `Application.Resources` and then `DefaultStyleKey`.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look [DataTemplate and Style Confusion](http://www.11011.net/archives/000692.html):

> I posted this as a "bug" on Connect in October 2006.
>
> ...
>
> "This behavior is 'By Design' and this is why. Templates are viewed as an encapsulation boundary. Elements produced by these templates fall within this boundary. And lookup for a style with a matching TargetType stops at this boundary. Hence the TextBlock in the repro which is produced through a template does not pick up the Style in question. Whereas the TextBlock defined outside the template does.
>
> One way to work around this problem is to give an explicit name to the Style and reference the style by this name on the TextBlock within the template.